# hawtio - predefined list of remote agents

Tags: java, monitoring, hawtio, jolokia

I'm working on an application which is comprised of many web containers with WAR-s installed on these containers.
Currently I have a farm of ~ 10 servers like this.
I'm about to start the integration of jolokia/hawtio to track the JMX mbeans exposed on each of these servers.

For this purpose (I think) I'll install a jolokia agent on each of these servers (just put the war into the deployment library. 
Now I think to put hawtio on a dedicated node and connect to the remote agents deployed on the rest of my 10 servers.

My question is whether its possible to somehow give a list of predefined agents (host/port/credentials)?

I have a lot of farms to manage like this, I would prefer to use a predefined list generated per farm, rather than dealing with auto-discovery

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No currently this is not supported, but a good idea. You are welcome to log a ticket about this.

- https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/issues

And also how would you like that list to be configured? Should you need to edit the web.xml and repackage the WAR, or how should that configuration be made easy? That is for something to think about.

Comment: Thanks for your response Claus. As you've asked I've opened an issue and presented my opinion. Its accessible here: https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/issues/1965